# Save Java propertyfile into XML format in specific order

Tags: java, xml, properties

I'm looking for a way to save my properties in a specific order.
The Property-class saves the values unsorted :/
Its important for me to save them in a specific order. Any way to do this when saving it to the XML format with storeToXML()? I want them in the order in which I have inserted them.

For Example:

```
put("Name","Frost");
put("Surname","Byte");
put("Age","18");
put("Country","Germany");
```

gets stored in this order:

```
<entry key="Name">Frost</entry>
<entry key="Country">Germany</entry>
<entry key="Surname">Byte</entry>
<entry key="Age">18</entry>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Properties` is the wrong approach to achieve this. `Properties` extends `Hashtable` which is a `HashMap` and therefore does not retain the order of your properties inserted.

You have to use another technology to write XML files that have a certain order. E.g. you can use JAXB to create the XML files directly from the involved objects.

Comment: Hmm I'll take a look at JAXB. Thanks :)
The Tutorials at Vogella seems easy http://www.vogella.com/articles/JAXB/article.html for those who have the same problem ;D

Answer (score 0):

You can extend Properties and delegate all map methods to a LinkedHashMap to preserve insertion order.
The below link is useful to you:
1.[How to read a properties file in java in the original order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619796/how-to-read-a-properties-file-in-java-in-the-original-order)

Comment: Thanks for the link. Thats also a possibility, but JAXB seems easier.
I wonder why Oracle don't uses a LinkedHashset :/

Comment: @KevinKuegler The class `Properties` is around since Java 1.0 and there `Properties` were only saved in plain text files where order is not important. Also Java 1.0 had no `LinkedHashMap`.