# Modifying Property File

Tags: java

I have a property file having different data. I need to update the value of  a property. How can achieve this using Java?

My property file contains:

> # Module Password for Installer
>   MODULE_PASSWORD=Mg==
>
> # Modules Selected for Installer
>   ausphur=yes
>   einfuhr=no
>   edec=no
>   emcs=no
>   ncts=no
>   suma=no
>   eas=no
>   zollager=no

I need to change yes or no values.

Comment: Use the `Properties` class?

Comment: Do you need to keep the comments?

Comment: Did you check out http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `FileOutputStream` to the properties file and modify the property by using `Properties.setProperty(PROPERTY_NAME,PROPERTY_VALUE)` and then call `store(out,null)` on `Properties` instance

```
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("config.properties");
        props.setProperty("ausphur", "no");
        props.store(out, null);
        out.close();
```

This will help!

**Update:**

There is no way to keep your comments back since `Properties` doesn't know about it. If you use `java.util.Properties`, it is a subclass of `Hashtable` which doesn't preserve the order of the keys and values the way they are inserted. What you can do is, you can go for `LinkedHashMap` collection with your own implementation of `Properties` datastore. But, you have to read the properties from file yourself and put it in `LinkedHashMap`. To Note, `LinkedHashMap` preserves the order in which keys are values are put. so, you can iterate the `keyset` and update the properties file in the same order back. Thus, the order can be preserved

Comment: no.File content gets changed.but its order changing and some comments are missing

Comment: it would be helpful for me if u could find the answer

Comment: I don't think the comments will be preserved since the file is rewritten with properties from memory. The order of the properties is also not preserved. i'm still confused with your expected output.Please clarify

Comment: you are right. The order of the property is not preserved.I need that to be preserved.

Comment: Please try `LinkedHashMap` with your own implementation

Comment: plz show me an example code

Comment: PleaseRefer this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619796/how-to-read-a-properties-file-in-java-in-the-original-order)

Comment: @Keerthivasan What if you have delimiters? ausphur = yes@!no@!no@!yes. Then how would you add a new value of "no" at the end of the current value?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Properties Java class.
It allows you to handle in a very easy way properties files based on (key, value) pair.
Have a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html
In particular:

> Saving Properties
>
> The following example writes out the application properties from the previous example using Properties.store. The >default properties don't need to be saved each time because they never change.
>
> FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("appProperties");
>   applicationProps.store(out, "---No Comment---");
>   out.close();
>   The store method needs a stream to write to, as well as a string that it uses as a comment at the top of the output.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
Properties prop = new Properties();
        OutputStream output = null;

```
        output = new FileOutputStream("config.properties");

        // set the properties value
        prop.setProperty("propertyname", "newValue");
        prop.store(output, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use java.util.Properties.

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("pathToYourFile");
    props.load(fis);
    fis.close();
    props.setProperty("propName", "propValue");
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("pathToYourFile");
    props.store(fos, "Your comments");
    fos.close();
```