# TreeMap getting exception "fromKey > toKey" (fromKey is greater than toKey?)

Tags: java, hashmap, treemap, treemaps

I've stored following xml attribute into

`HashMap<String, String> extraParams = new HashMap<String, String>()`

```
<parameter name="sourceAttrStart" value="true" />
<parameter name="user" value="admin" />
<parameter name="password" value="password" />
<parameter name="SQL" value="SELECT * FROM test.users" />
<parameter name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
<parameter name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://tesco-db.ce7gg2eo7hdc.us-
<parameter name="sourceAttrEnd" value="true" />
```

Basically I want to get subset of hashmap between kets `sourceAttrStart` to `sourceAttrEnd`

This what I'm trying

```
TreeMap<String, String> sorted = new TreeMap<String, String>(extraParams);

SortedMap<String, String> sourceParams = sorted.subMap("sourceAttrStart", "sourceAttrEnd");
```

But getting below exception, any idea why?

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: fromKey > toKey
    at java.util.TreeMap$NavigableSubMap.<init>(TreeMap.java:1368)
    at java.util.TreeMap$AscendingSubMap.<init>(TreeMap.java:1855)
    at java.util.TreeMap.subMap(TreeMap.java:913)
    at java.util.TreeMap.subMap(TreeMap.java:954)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TreeMap` uses the natural order (`compareTo()` method) of keys to order the elements.
The `"sourceAttrEnd"` `String` is before the `"sourceAttrStart"` `String` in terms of `compareTo()`.
Whereas the thrown exception as you invoke `TreeMap.subMap("sourceAttrStart", "sourceAttrEnd")` :

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: fromKey > toKey

Whatever adding the elements in a `HashMap` and then using the `HashMap` object to create a sorted collection will not allow to make them ordered as you wish as `HashMap` doesn't guarantee the order of elements.
So as alternative, you could add the elements in a [`LinkedHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) as soon as the loading of the file as  `LinkedHashMap` maintains the order of elements according to their insertion order.
But the `Properties` class is not designed to keep the order of appearance of the elements.  To allow that you should extend `Properties`.
Here is an interesting [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3619917/270371).

Beyond the way to use, `.properties` files are not also designed to have a specific order of elements.
So I think that a better alternative would be to use the `Property` class and get from it the entries you need. You could define entries keys in a `List` for example.

Here is a basic example :

```
Properties props = ...; // load your file
List<String> keysToRetrieve = Arrays.asList("sourceAttrStart", "user", ..., "sourceAttrEnd");

Map<String, String> entriesToRetrieve = new HashMap<>();
for (String key : keysToRetrieve){
   entriesToRetrieve.put(key, props.getProperty(key)); 
}
```

Comment: actually It's `TestNG` xml values I retrived as `Map<String, String> extraParams = context.getCurrentXmlTest().getSuite()
    .getParameters();`, I'm not sure will it maintain's the insertion order or not :(

Comment: _"Whatever adding the elements in a HashMap and then using the HashMap object to create a sorted collection..."_ I think it is irrelevant of how the sorted map is created.  It is simply OP's understanding on a sorted map is wrong.  TreeMap does not sort by insertion order.

Comment: @Adrian Shum  You are right and more generally relying on the order of elements in a ".properties" file is probably not the way to follow.

Comment: @Swapnil Kotwal I updated. I think trying to maintain the order is not the way.

Answer (score 2):

`TreeMap` sort keys in lexicographical order.
String `"sourceAttrEnd"` is before `"sourceAttrStart"` in such order.

Comment: To be accurate, TreeMap does NOT sort **keys** in lexicographical order.  It sort keys in lexicographical order only when type of key is String, and without special comparator